# how to add images to adf mobile project?

Tags: android, oracle-adf

I'm unable to figure out how I can add images with different versions like ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi in `Oracle ADF Mobile`. When using native development, we have folders with different naming conventions `drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc`, but in ADF there is only one folder in folder structure. So unable to figure out where to add images with different resolutions. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your project, there is **no place** to add images with different resolutions.

JDeveloper ADF Mobile isn't native development, it leverages the Cordova platform (HTML5 + Javascript) to create a hybrid app. So you won't see an area inside your project to place your scaled Android images (drawable-hdpi, etc.) or Retina-ready iOS images (image@2x.png, etc.) like you would in Xcode or Eclipse. The exception is the splash screens, which do in fact allow you to set various-density default images for Android and iOS. You can set these in the Deployment Profile Properties pane when you go to deploy an app.

All other images inside your app will scale. If binary file size is a concern, be conservative, but generally you should go for the highest density image based on the device you are targeting (higher for tablet deployments, less for iPhones, etc.)